# Can of chicken left in hot car - okay or trash

Tags: food-safety, meat

I bought a can of chicken (chunk white meat) a while back. Because I wasn't "deliberately shopping for groceries" (I was at the store returning bottles for deposit, but had earlier realized my meal plans were short by one can of chicken), that was all I bought, and as a result, I ended up tossing it in the glove box and forgetting about it for about a week.

When I finally brought it in, it was rather warm, and presumably had been heating and cooling every day it was left in the car.

Is it still safe to eat? Obviously, if it was something that would normally be refrigerated, the answer would be a very emphatic "no", but being canned, it has already been cooked to death and (at least in theory) sealed into a sterile environment, and doesn't need to be kept refrigerated. (Note: the can is *not* bulging noticeably, which I do know would indicate that it is definitely *not* safe.)

p.s. I read https://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16796 but it doesn't say if exposure to higher temperatures is an issue. OTOH, a comment on [this question](/questions/73180) suggests it may have already been exposed to similar conditions.

p.p.s. I don't plan on keeping this around for another 2-3 years; the intention would be to eat it within about a month.

Comment: When in doubt, Trash it.

Comment: @Max There are certainly circumstances where 'doubt' is subjective, though, and in this case I do think the OP is worrying over nothing.

Comment: Saving it for special occasion? Did you eat it?    I'm trying to find a way to store canned Tuna, Chili and Ravioli UNDERGROUND near Lake Placid Florida ( around 27.2, 81.3).  This particular land is high, but soil is    cool a few feet down.  I'm thinking a sealed thick plastic container 3 feet under ground, under thick canopy of trees and maybe even a small structure.  I can't imagine it will ever be over 80F inside the container in the middle of the day in Summer.  wonder what self life will be? I just need them to keep through the summer (4 months).

Answer (score 26):

Referencing [Shelf-Stable Food Safety](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/wcm/connect/77ffde83-dc51-4fdf-93be-048110fe47d6/Shelf_Stable_Food_Safety.pdf?MOD=AJPERES), from The Food Safety and Inspection Service in the US.

> There are several factors that limit the shelf life of canned foods. First, cans can rust over time. Shipping accidents, where cans fall and dent or are crushed, also cause container problems.
>
> Then there’s can corrosion. In all foods, but especially in high-acid foods like
> canned tomatoes, natural chemicals in the food continually react with the
> container. Over several years, this can cause taste and texture changes, and
> eventually lower the nutritional value of the food.
>
> High temperatures (over 100 °F) are harmful to canned goods too. The risk
> of spoilage jumps sharply as storage temperatures rise. In fact, canned goods
> designed for use in the tropics are specially manufactured.

The exact determination here depends on exactly how hot the interior of your glovebox was getting on particularly hot days, but that's impossible to know. Personally, I doubt that the temperature ever reached dangerous levels and would just enjoy my can of chicken.

However, you may have different tolerance for risk levels than I would, so I hope that the information I've provided is sufficient for you to make a decision of your own. The absolute 0% risk determination would be to simply throw it away. It's your choice.

Comment: Just use common sense. If the can isn't damaged (for example the ends aren't bulging), the contents look OK and smell OK, and if you cook them thoroughly (rather than just warming them up a bit to kick any bacteria back into life) eating the contents won't do you any serious harm.

Comment: Note that it's ***really*** easy for a car outside in the sun to hit 100F inside. It totally depends on the weather conditions. 80F and sunny? I wouldn't chance it for a $4 can of chicken. But my appetite (bada-bing) for risk on these things is low.

Comment: An average car parked for an hour in average sun will reach about 47C (116F) inside.  A dark car left longer and in hotter sun can reach in excess of 80C (180F).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, $4? Sheesh, chicken must be expensive where you live. Alas, I have since mixed it up with a second can such that now I wouldn't know which was which. (Also, re-cook already cooked chicken? Bleh.) Oh, well, I need to go back to the store anyway...

Comment: @Matthew - I took a wild guess, actually; I live in the UK and (separately) don't recall the last time I bought a can of cooked chicken (if ever). :-) Last time I was in the U.S. prices seemed really high to me, so.. :-D

Comment: @alephzero But I've read that if you're dealing with botulism, heating won't do anything to get rid of the toxins produced by the bacteria, which is what harms you anyway, and I believe is the big concern with canned goods. So I'm not sure heating it up is any insurance against food born illness in this case. If it's tainted with botulism, you'll still get sick/die, even if you heat it.

Comment: @bob That’s not true. Botulinum toxin is readily destroyed at boiling temperatures.

Comment: @Sneftel Interesting. It appears to be time and temperature specific. Not sure I'd want to play that game personally.

Comment: @bob Of course it’s time and temperature specific. All cooking is time and temperature specific.

Comment: Sure. Wasn't arguing but just commenting for folks who may not be familiar with food safety. Not everyone may realize that "heat to boiling" isn't necessarily enough; they need to actually track the temperature and keep track of the time, and make sure it's gotten hot enough for long enough, especially given how dangerous this particular bug is. Of course I'd just toss the can in that case and not eat it. But everyone is different.

Comment: No, they don’t. Botulinum toxin is destroyed well below boiling temperature with significant time, but at boiling it’s basically instant. Overstating the dangers of botulism - a disease which hasn’t led to any serious cases stemming from commercially canned food in many years - encourages people to focus on it specifically while ignoring more likely, and overall more dangerous, food-borne illnesses (whose toxins are *not* destroyed by boiling). It’s a paradoxically counterproductive alarmism.

Answer (score -3):

You know canned food isn't supposed to be stored in hot environments. A week of hot/cold cycles is way too much. It's actually temperature shock (extreme changes) which can quicken spoilage of many things that are otherwise "stable" by the way. There are people who died horribly painful deaths after eating a meal they left out too long for just 1 day. Think about it.

On the point of temperature shock: "Inappropriate storage temperatures or **fluctuations** in storage temperature are the most avoidable causes of spoilage" -- [Understanding poultry products spoilage](https://www.wattagnet.com/articles/4207-understanding-poultry-products-spoilage)

If you think temperature cycles in your car will "reset" the safety of food each day as it cycles through temperatures:
"Some bacteria, such as staphylococcus (staph) and Bacillus cereus, produce toxins not destroyed by high cooking temperatures. Refrigerate perishable foods within 2 hours in a refrigerator temperature of 40 degrees or below." -- [Food Safety Myths, Washington State Dept. of Health.](https://www.doh.wa.gov/YouandYourFamily/FoodSafety/Myths#:%7E:text=Perishable%20foods%20should%20be%20put,for%20more%20than%202%20hours.). So actually the food could be becoming more deadly the longer it is in there as toxins accumulate.

"Yes, heat is the enemy of all canned goods. Food stored in cans will spoil quickly if exposed to high temperatures, especially over 95 degrees F. It's best to store all your food in a temperature controlled environment that is kept at or below 70 degrees F." -- [Does Canned Food Go Bad in the Heat?](https://crisisequipped.com/does-canned-food-go-bad-in-the-heat)

On a side note I've done experiments myself with food preservatives and observed that when food is stored in conditions that minimize how suddenly temperature changes it will be preserved much longer than otherwise. Not that you have to take my word for it.

Comment: Got any sources for your claims?

Comment: @Mark I've added some notes.

Comment: Those sources have good food storage/spoilage info, but they don't address anything specific to canned foods.

Comment: @NuclearWang I honestly thought that canned food going bad at high temp was too obvious to need a cite but i've added one!